# Wildmenu for command line history

Tags: command-line

While there is `<up>` and `<down>` that tries to complete the line, sometimes one wants to recall all the commands that start with what was typed, on a (wild)menu.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use FZF to complete the command by using the command history.

Unfortunately, I had to get out of the command line to do so, but it still fairly comfortable. I could edit the command afterwards if I want to.

```
function! GetCommands()
    let lines=[]
    let nu=histnr("cmd")
    for i in range(1,nu)
        let lines+=[histget("cmd",i)]
    endfor
    return lines
endfunction

function! HandleCommand(item)
    call feedkeys("q:")
    call feedkeys("G?\\V".escape(a:item,'\/?')."\<CR>")
endfunction

function! CompleteCommand(arg)
call fzf#run({'source': GetCommands(),'sink': function('HandleCommand'),'options': '-m --query "'.a:arg.'"'} ) 
endfunction 


:cmap <expr> <c-a> &cedit.'^"xy$'."<esc><esc>:call CompleteCommand(@x)<CR>"

:autocmd CmdwinEnter * map <buffer> <ESC> <C-c><C-c>
```